# Does GCC optimize code to remove useless variable read operations?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler

I'm using GCC on ununtu 14.04. My program is written in c++ and in a case i need to check the amount of time the program needs to read a large integer array. what is the best way to do this without causing unnecessary compiler optimization?

Comment: Maybe `volatile` will do the trick.

Comment: @Doval that will read from RAM each time and probably ignore any caching that may happen (and it will with a linear read from an array)

Comment: Reading an array from where? Is it already in memory, or in a file? Is the file cached? Should it be? Would you expect the memory to be in L3, L2, L1 cache? Do you want the worst case or the likely case, and do you know what that is?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489

Comment: @useless as that is not mentioned, you are obviously  expected to answer to each case.

Comment: Why do you want your code to read from me empty any more than it has to?

Comment: I'm more concerned with the time it takes to read from the variables =)

Comment: So then you *want* the compiler to optimize the reads away, right?

Comment: No I want the compiler to take more time. It's crazy. But it's for research.

Comment: search brought me here... I tested that -O3 will not optimize out a *read from a volatile* even if the variable being read into is unused (and not volatile) and would otherwise be a candidate for removal. Reason: I wanted to read a hardware register to avoid an overrun interrupt (for failing to read it), but I didn't care about the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will optimize the reads out if it sees the result is unused, even more if the compiler sees the entire loop body is empty the entire loop may become optimized away.

You will need to do another operation with the result to ensure the reads remain. Xoring the integers together is a simple example, calling a function with it as a parameter that the compiler can't optimize away (because it may have side effects).

Having said all that just reading the array is not a useful metric in itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If I were to say call an empty function passing the variables, and maybe adding them in the function, would that work? The stay is expected to be in the l3 cache

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am misunderstanding your requirements, the 'volatile' keyword may be sufficient for your desire to prevent undesired optimization.  I tested the following using GCC version 4.6.3 and verified  the reading of the array elements into *x* was never optimized away (tested with -O0, -O1, -O2 and -O3 optimization levels).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[1024];

int main (void) {
    volatile int  x;
    int           i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        x = array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.